# How to create scheduledtasks without credentials from python?

Tags: django, windows, scheduled-tasks

Users of my app can click on a link which call a function that create a .bat file (does it fine) and scheduledtask that will call that .bat file. My problem is in invoked [RegisterTaskDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/taskfolder-registertaskdefinition) function (called by pywin32 library object). No matter kind of login strategy I choose, I'm getting an exception in any case.But I need create tasks without credentials, so how can I achieve it?
Capture of exception
[image]

My RegisterTaskDefinition configuration:

```
root_folder.RegisterTaskDefinition(
        '{}_blabla'.format(self.datasource.name),  # Task name
        task_def,
        TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
        '',  # No user
        '',  # No password
        0)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the `django-windowsauth` package, it does all that for your. Just use the `createtask` command to add a management command to task scheduler.

https://django-windowsauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/create_tasks.html

(You can also take a look at the source code if you need some more inspiration...)